# mongoose .populate not working

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using nodejs/express and mongoose. However, when trying to use `.populate(...)` on a document it doesn't work. Here is my code:

I have this schema for a User:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({

    ...

    friends: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        },
        ...
    }],
    sentRequests: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        },
        ...
    }],
    recievedRequests: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        },
        ...
    }]
}
mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Then when I try to show all the recievedRequests to a page I use this code:

```
router.get('/friendRequests', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
            _id: req.user.id // where req.user is the currently logged in user
    })
    .populate('recievedRequests.user')
    .then(curUser => {
        res.render('friends/friendRequests', {
            curUser: curUser
        });
    })
});
```

where `User` is the model and `req.user.id` is the id of the currently logged in user. However, in the webpage whenever I reference `curUser.recievedRequests.user` it simply returns the id of the user and not the actual user object. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks.

**EDIT - Example**

For a document:

```
user1 = {
    _id: ObjectId("5ae94b0b2bb9383d4029d64b"),
    ...
    recievedRequests: [
        {"_id" : ObjectId("5ae94b5f29c86c4a343d2d0a") }
    ]        
}
```

and

```
user2 = {
    _id: ObjectId("5ae94b5f29c86c4a343d2d0a"),
    ...
}
```

Using my above code on this document:

```
router.get('/friendRequests', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
            _id: user1.id
    })
    .populate('recievedRequests.user')
    .then(curUser => {
        res.render('friends/friendRequests', {
            curUser: curUser
        });
    })
});
```

results in `curUser.recievedRequests = [{ _id : 5ae94b5f29c86c4a343d2d0a }]`

Comment: What is the actual registered model name? i.e when you did `mongoose.model('<modelName>', <modelSchema>)` then what did you actually put in the `<modelName>` part? Also show at least two documents that you expect to "match" by this reference

Comment: That's included under the schema (`mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);`). I updated to include an example

Comment: `2` is NOT an `ObjectId`. Show your real documents, "both" the one with the `receivedRequests` you expect to match to and the `"user"` that matches one of the values in that array at least. If they are in fact "numbers" then that's your clear problem since the schema types don't match. But we cannot debug unless you show the "real data" otherwise.

Comment: Sorry I realised that after, has been updated.

Comment: Also the [`mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) should be used for displaying documents. Simple `console.log()` statements ( or other tools ) do not show the correct "type" information which is inherent to the question you are asking. So we need to see whether things are `ObjectId` or just a "string" or other incorrect "type". And you have not "updated" anything.

Comment: Updated to correspond to my real documents.